# Lazy load with List View Titanium

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

Am using 3.1.3.GA sdk, Alloys and 2.3.4 Android Emulator. With List View, I created items to show and there are around 300 items I have to show in List View. As per TableView we can use scroll event for lazy load, but List View doesnt support scroll event and now how can I lazy load contents to my List View. Is it possible or else we have to go for TableView only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Answered in [Appcelerator Q&A](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/159149/list-view-support-to-scroll) by Sergey Nosenko ,i am sharing here so that it may help others ,facing the same issue

[List-View-module](https://github.com/darknos/TiAdvancedListView)

Comment: Now better to use TableView until next official release arrives with marker support for ListView.